# How to use Customize Model extends from User Model in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I have a problem that makes me quite confused. I have a page when users click to change profile, the corresponding page shows up and lets users update their profile. Here is my model:

```py
from django.db import models

import os
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


# Create your models here.
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete="CASCADE")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    room = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    dob = models.DateField(default=timezone.datetime.now())
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default=os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'avatar.png'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Here are my forms:

```py
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                                 widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'uk-input', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'uk-input', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['phone', 'room', 'dob', 'active', 'avatar']
```

And I have my views.py like this:

```py
def show_form(request):
    user_basic_info = UserForm(request.POST)
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid() and user_basic_info.is_valid():
        form.save() and user_basic_info.save()
        messages.sucess(request, _('Your profile has been successfully updated'))
        redirect('my_account')
    else:
        UserForm()
        ProfileForm()
    context = {
        'user_basic_info': user_basic_info,
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'my_account.html', context)
```

Here is my_account.html template:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}My account{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumb %}
  <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Update your information</li>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10">
      <form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% include 'includes/form.html' %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save changes</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And forms.html:

```html
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<table>
    <div class="form-group">############

{{ user_basic_info }} ############# This displays first_name, last_name and email. Also the problem's here, I want to make 2 forms in one form with a better style like the form below.
    </div>############
</table>
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
      <p{% if forloop.last %} class="mb-0"{% endif %}>{{ error }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endif %}

{% for field in form %}
<div class="form-group">
    {{ field.label_tag }} {% if form.is_bound %} {% if field.errors %} {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %} {% for error in field.errors %}
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
        {{ error }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %} {% else %} {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" %} {% endif %} {% else %} {% render_field field class="form-control" %} {% endif %} {% if field.help_text %}
    <small class="form-text text-muted">
        {{ field.help_text|safe }}
      </small> {% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

So when users want to change their profile, those fields `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `phone`, `room`, `dob`, `active`, `avatar` need to be displayed. But the first 3 fields belong to the User model and the rest fields are defined in my Account model. I want when users submit the form, those fields are linked together, e.g **Account is an instance of User** and that information is properly saved to the database in Account model (I have watched some tutorials but I still cannot properly do it). And when logging to the page, login authentication using User model, but when updating the profile it's Account model and User model, but there is no relationship between them, how can I fix all of those errors, thanks in advance.

Comment: Anobdy please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `OneToOne` Relationship here since each user has only one and unique profile details. so in your `models.py` use :-

```
user                = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use default user there is 4 way to extends it so here i give a link follow them,

> if you use default user you need to use `Usercreation` form for Register because the user model have **password encryption algorithm**use so when you use you user define form it will not store your password

- follow instruction for extends user abstract base model

  1. extends user using
  2. registration form using `usercreation` form
  3. Define view of save data
- follow instruction for extends user using one to one

  1. Create new model Profile and give one to one relationship
  2. Create registration form usring `model.form`plus additional fields you want to take from user define in form class explicity
  3. in view save form and add user reference in Profile model using create method

link:

1. [extend user model](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#abstractuser)
2. [if you use usercreation form](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html)

go through i give link if you got error let me know